# How to get a data from an analysis in R in Json file format to get D3 visualisations?

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js

I wanted to get the Json file as result for an analysis and just give as input for the D3 code and get the visualisations ...Is there any way

I tried searching many things in R to get result as a json file but no improvements.

Comment: Is this shiny application?

Comment: Maybe [the d3r package](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/d3r) ? That depends on the kind of visualization you want.

Comment: Sure, but what have you tried? See [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using shiny, then you can send message from R to JavaScript like reverse Ajax:

First you need handler in JS:

```
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("d3vis", function(json) {
   //d3 code that process json data
});
```

> NOTE: by default Shiny object will not be defined because it
>   initialized in `setTimeout(0)` inside jQuery ready function, so you
>   also need `$(function() { setTimeout(init, 0); });` and inside init
>   function you call your custom event handler.

and in R you send the message:

```
## example data
data <- list(
  x = list(1, 2, 3),
  y = list(10, 20, 30)
)
session$sendCustomMessage("d3vis", data)
```

data will be converted to JSON by shiny send using websockets or XHR long pulling depend on settings and will be parsed in JavaScript and your handler will be called where you can use D3 to render visualization.

Also you can use interactive visualizations using reactiveness:

```
observe({
  ## reactive data
  data <- list(
     x = list(input$x1, input$x2, input$x3),
     y = list(input$y1, input$y2, input$y3)
   )
   session$sendCustomMessage("d3vis", data)
})
```